# Python scraper with multiprocess

Tags: python, lxml, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I'm currently learning to use python and my first objectif is to scrape every articles in every pages of my website.

I would like to get all articles in the first page and scrap title on each articles and when it's finish i would like to go in the next page and do the same thing.

Actually i can scrap all links and the first page and the multiprocess get the links of first page indefinitely. I don't know how i can in the same time scrap the title of all links scraped and scrap links in each page of the website.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from lxml import html
import requests
import multiprocessing
import concurrent.futures

i = 0

def get_informations(link):
    page = requests.get('http://myWebsite.com/'+link)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    titre = tree.xpath('//*[@id="infosSpectacle"]/ul/li[1]/h2/text()')
    print titre

while True:
    page = requests.get('http://myWebsite.com/Articles?Page='+str(i))
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    links = tree.xpath("//a/@href")
    links = set(links)

    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(10)
    futures = [executor.submit(get_informations, link) for link in links]
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
    i =+ 1    
    #How can I go to the second page with the Process ??
```

Thanks for your help